# How do I get the current DOM with Selenium Java 2.8?

Tags: dom, selenium, junit, zk

I'm using the latest version of Selenium and the `chromedriver` to test a ZK application.

During the test, I'd like to dump the DOM (or part of it) to help me find the elements I need (and probably help people who have to maintain the test).

The method `WebDriver.getPageSource()` looked promising but it only returns the HTML as it was sent by the server, not the result after running all the JavaScript code.

The JavaScript code is run; I can find elements by ID that I can't see in the output of `getPageSource()`. So I tried `WebElement.getText()` but that is only the text of the elements, not the elements themselves or their attributes.

Is it possible at all to get the DOM or do I have to do keyhole surgery here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same question really but the only way I've found to do it is ExecuteScript:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets the parentElement/Node of a particular element
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="driver"></param>
        /// <param name="element"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IWebElement GetElementParent(IWebDriver driver,IWebElement element)
        {
            return (IWebElement) ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].parentNode", element);
        }
```

why the By doesnt support By.DOM with a function I don't really know...I suspect its due to the need for a webdriver for multiple browsers etc

Comment: Okay, since the page contains jQuery, I could get what I want by running `$(arguments[0]).html()`, I guess :-/