# chromedriver - Javascript is not rendered

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would use Selenium with Cromedrive to test website in VisualStudio.
Problem is that I don't see items genrated by Javascript on page. It looks like chromedriver take pagesource before JS run.
I spent 3 days with this topic but it still not running.

I found lot of suggestions like wait for whole page load

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://...");   
driver.WaitForPageToLoad();

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
```

or different ways to wait for element load

```
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); 
 waitForElement.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("div.list-item[userid=2]")));
```

I also tried different ways to execute javascript and get innerHTML

```
uid.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

..but nothing help.

I had just one progress when I used PhantomJS driver. It is running fine but I need to test it with chrome.

It looks like drivers render pages in different way.

ChromeDriver

```
<div class="list-item" on-click="{{selectUser}}" userid="{{u.id}}">
```

PhantomJSDriver

```
<div class="list-item" on-click="{{ selectUser }}" userid="2">
```

Chrome elemnts is same view as PhantomJS

```
<div class="list-item" on-click="{{ selectUser }}" userid="2"> ==$0
```

Do you have any idea how to get same pagesource in ChromeDriver as in Chrome ?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are confusing page source with "current DOM": page source is roughly the page as delivered by the server, with some implementation differences for various browsers, like you noticed for Chrome vs PhantomJS. What you want though is seems "current DOM" - how page looks like now, after JS/AJAX changes applied to it.  See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712771/how-do-i-get-the-current-dom-with-selenium-java-2-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution:

```
IWebElement elename = ((RemoteWebElement)driver).FindElementByCssSelector("whatyousearch");
```

In my case it is :

```
IWebElement uid ((RemoteWebElement)shadowRoot3).FindElementByCssSelector("div[userid='2']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply. It looks like "current DOM" is what I need. Thanks for hint. Problem is when I execute script for parentNode then I see all variables from JS in text only.[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZqPv.jpg)

I also can use first value for FindElement() but pagesource is still same.
[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAVt1.jpg)

I understand what you mean that pagesource is what was delivered from server (without JS modification) but I need to see it as current DOM (like pagesource from PhantomJS driver with rendered JS).

I tried it with innerHTML and this is what I exactly need

[Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le6rF.jpg)

but I can' use it with FindElement(By)

[Pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkIqr.jpg)

Any idea how to add current DOM to pagesource or how to use values which I get with parentNote with FindElement and be able to do some action like .Click() ?